# ios how to implement facebook login authentication to use my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

I implementing app but one of the condition of the app is for the user to use the facebook account to login. Any of you has implemented something like that? if you have can you please point me to a example or documentation of how can implement this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow along with this guide/ tutorial that Facebook provides: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/ They basically go through building a sample app that has a lot of the basic functions an app integrated with facebook might need.